# how to put a many bunch of orphan tags in other tag using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have some tags in bunches which are not placed in any tag.
but I need to put it in a  tag until the next serial tag is coming

I have tried the same but for every orphan tag will be getting placed in different sections which is not as expected

Input Xml:

```
<title>Info111</title>
<ul> underline<ul>
<li>list</li>
<serial>
    <em>this is for em</em>
    <title>serial title</title>
</serial>
<title>Info2222</title>
<ul> underline2222<ul>
<li>li for list</li>
```

my xslt code:

```
<xsl:variable name='list' select='//serial'/>

<xsl:template match='/'>

        <xsl:for-each select='$list'>
            <xsl:element name='serial'>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='*[not(name(.)="serial")]'/>

            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

actual output

```
:
<serial>
<title>Info111</title>
</serial>
<serial>
     <ul> underline<ul>
</serial>
<serial>
      <li>list</li>
</serial>
<serial>
    <em>this is for em</em>
    <title>serial title</title>
</serial>
<serial>
    <title>Info2222</title>
</serial>
<serial>
    <ul> underline2222<ul>
</serial>
<serial>
<li>li for list</li>
</serial>
```

Expected Output :

```
<serial>
     <title>Info111</title>
     <ul> underline<ul>
     <li>list</li>
</serial>

<serial>
    <em>this is for em</em>
    <title>serial title</title>
</serial>

<serial>
    <title>Info2222</title>
    <ul> underline2222<ul>
    <li>li for list</li>
</serial>
```

Please help me to resove this issue

Comment: Which XSLT version can you use?

Comment: xslt 2.0 version

Comment: Please help me for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps everyone if you use correct terminology. I think that by "tags" you probably mean "elements". (Elements actually have two tags, a start tag and an end tag). I initially had no idea what you meant by "bunches", but on studying your example I decided you meant "groups".

The input you show is not a complete document. In well-formed XML, there is always a root element. So I don't know what you mean by "orphan tags" - every element in well-formed XML has a parent node.

And while we're talking about your question, it helps everyone with XSLT questions if you put an "xslt 1.0" or "xslt 2.0" or "xslt 3.0" tag on the question ("tag" in the StackOverflow sense, not the XML sense) as that will often affect the answer.

The XSLT code you show is only processing elements in $list, that is, elements named "serial". So I don't see how you can be getting output containing, for example, Info111 and Info222.

The XSLT 2.0 code for this is:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::serial)">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::serial">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <serial><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></serial>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes you are right that every tag has parent tag in xml but here orphan tag I mean is the tags which are not under serial tags.

Comment: my xml is :

<content><body><title>Info111</title>
<ul> underline<ul>
<li>list</li>
<serial>
    <em>this is for em</em>
    <title>serial title</title>
</serial>
<title>Info2222</title>
<ul> underline2222<ul>
<li>li for list</li></body></content>

Comment: When I have tried with your solution . I am getting the below error:                   xsl:for-each-group is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet! and my output is same as input xml.No changes has been reflected.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>             <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template><xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::serial)">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::serial"><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <serial><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></serial>
    </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group></xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: `xsl:for-each-group` is an instruction, it needs to go inside a template rule.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve the expected output using xalan

Comment: please suggest if there is any other way to do this via xalan

Comment: @RichaBajaj I last used XSLT 1.0 in anger about 20 years ago: you might find someone here to help you with it, but it won't be me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your respons!
Now it is working fine with below code.

```
<xsl:template match="content/body">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::serial)">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::serial">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <serial><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></serial>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

and I am getting the expected output:)